# Serve electron.js frontend on LAN

Tags: node.js, electron, lan

I'm trying to get electron.js app to work on lan, in dev is pretty easy, you just access ip:port (on quasar/electron app is port 9300) and it just works, but on build I can't get the same result. I know it could be done manually like storing the frontend and serving it via node.js, but I wonder if there is an easier out of the box approach just like in dev mode. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> you just access ip:port (on quasar/electron app is port 9300)

I think this socket is just being used, after using `quasar dev -m electron`, solely to do the live updates of any code changes.

The whole point of the Electron version is it gives you a standalone executable that doesn't need to be served by a web server; the downside being that each user has to install it.

If you meant serving a web app, not an electron app, then this page in the documentation on might be helpful: [Opening Your Dev Server to the Public](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/opening-dev-server-to-public)

That is for vite, but [the instructions for webpack](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/opening-dev-server-to-public/) look to be exactly identical; they are showing examples for localhost.run and Ngrok.

Beyond that, setting up a "real" web server, whether using node-express, Apache, or anything between, is not that much extra work. Remember to have it listen on a LAN IP address (or 0.0.0.0) and make sure the dev machine's firewall doesn't block access.

Comment: Hi!, Thanks for your answer, I'm aware of those methods, but this specific question is because I already have an electron.js app working on lan serving itself via express, so other users of the network can access it, the only problem is that I have to duplicate the frontend in order to access it, I need to put it in a public folder or somewhere, I'v been investigating where this frontend is stored, and is somewhere like /tmp/projectName/compressedFile and makes the public file inaccessible so I need to download it from somewhere and write it to the user pc which is like a lot of extra effort

Comment: I'm more confused now :-)  You might have to show a minimal reproducible example, or show more precisely what you are building, and how you are building it, to get a useful answer.